# Why in CSS, #1 (as id of a div element) styling doesn't work?

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="image" id="1"></div>
<div class="image" id="2"></div>
<div class="image" id="3"></div>
```

http://codepen.io/Chrez/pen/KdWrBe

As you see in the codepen the styling of "id='1'" doesn't work.

I need it this way because it's for slider, and my jQuery functions work this way.

Comment: You might make my answer as accepted answer if you got the answer you were looking for. It will help other people to know the same information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its CSS's rule that you can't use Number as starting character or a class or id. That is why it wont work. You at least have to put 1 alphabet before the number!

This is what said in w3c -

> In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in selectors) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646 characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore (_); they cannot start with a digit, two hyphens, or a hyphen followed by a digit. Identifiers can also contain escaped characters and any ISO 10646 character as a numeric code (see next item). For instance, the identifier “B&W?” may be written as “B\&W\?” or “B\26 W\3F”.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters

Comment: Also note: two hyphens does actually work in many browsers because of a proposed inclusion of CSS variables starting `--`. As you posted though it isn't in the actual W3C lexicon for identifiers. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/grammar.html#scanner

Answer (score 2):

Yes, we can't use `#1` according with w3c, but this little css-hack will work: `div[id="1"]` or just `.image[id="1"]`